# Proper implementation of triangular solver for sparse matrix with OpenACC

Tags: solver, openacc, triangular

I'm currently implementing triangular solver for sparse matrix and I've try to accelerate then using OpenACC directives. Given my matrix factors LU in sparse CSR format, OpenACC have managed to solve the L factor properly but the U factor gives completely wrong when compared with the true solution of the application. Here is the code of the accelerated kernel for the backward substitution task:

```
#pragma acc kernels deviceptr( ia, ja, factorValsU, y, x )
{
    for ( int idx = size; idx > 0; idx-- )
    {
        double temp = 0.0;
        int rowInit = ia[ idx - 1];
        int rowEnd  = ia[ idx ];
        #pragma acc loop vector reduction( + : temp)
        for ( int k = rowInit + 1; k < rowEnd; k++ )
        {
            temp += factorValsU[ k ] * x[ ja[ k ] ];
        }
        x[ idx ] = (y[ idx ] - temp) / factorValsU[ rowInit ];
    }
 }
```

I'm clueless about why this kernels does produce incorrect result. I've already tried a different version for the kernel where the matrix is saved backwards, i.e from down to top, which in principle could be solved with the follow kernel:

```
#pragma acc kernels deviceptr( ia, ja, factorValsU, y, x )
{
    for ( int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++ )
    {
        double temp = 0.0;
        int rowInit = ia[ idx ];
        int rowEnd  = ia[ idx + 1 ];
        #pragma acc loop vector reduction( + : temp)
        for ( int k = rowInit + 1; k < rowEnd; k++ )
        {
            temp += factorValsU[ k ] * x[ ja[ k ] ];
        }
        x[ size - idx ] = (y[ size - idx ] - temp) / factorValsU[ rowInit ];
    }
 }
```

But the result is always wrong. Did I miss something fundamental about decorating regular code with OpenACC directives to achieve proper results?

As mentioned before, the forward substitution of the L factor is properly working so, for completeness I do post the code here.

```
#pragma acc kernels deviceptr( ia, ja, factorValsL, y, x )
{
    for ( int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++ )
    {
        double temp = 0.0;
        int rowInit = ia[ idx ];
        int rowEnd  = ia[ idx + 1 ];
        #pragma acc loop vector reduction( + : temp)
        for ( int k = rowInit; k < rowEnd; k++ )
        {
            temp += factorValsL[ k ] * x[ ja[ k ] ];
        }
        x[ idx ] = y[ idx ] - temp;
    }
 }
```

Note the subtle difference between the kernel for the forward substitution (works) and backward substitution (both not working), is memory region where the result are saved:

```
x[ idx ] = y[ idx ] - temp     for the L factor 
x[ size - idx ] = (y[ size - idx ] - temp) / factorValsU[ rowInit ] for the U factor;
```

Is there some reason for the U factor solver to compute mistaken results cause of the order in which the assignation (and lecture) in memory is made?.

For completeness, the information provided by the pgi18.4 compiler about the kernel is:

```
triangularSolverU_acc(int, const int *, const int *, const double *, const double *, double *, bool):
614, Complex loop carried dependence of y->,x->,factorVals-> prevents parallelization
     Loop carried dependence of x-> prevents parallelization
     Loop carried backward dependence of x-> prevents vectorization
     Accelerator kernel generated
     Generating Tesla code
    614, #pragma acc loop seq
    621, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
         Generating reduction(+:temp)
621, Loop is parallelizable
```

Which shows that the external loop have been serialized and the inner loop is a reduction.

Answer (score 1):

With "kernels", the compiler must prove that the loop does not contain any dependencies and therefor is safe to parallelize.  However since your code contains pointers, and that pointers may be aliased to the same memory, the compiler can't prove this so does the safe thing and make the loop run sequential.  To override the compiler analysis, you can add a "#pragma acc loop independent" before the outer for loop.  The "independent" is an assertion to the compiler that the loop is safe to parallelize.  Alternatively, you can use the "parallel loop" directive in place of "kernels" since "parallel" implies "independent".

For the wrong answers, these are often due to the data not properly being synchronized between the host and device copies.  How are you managing the data movement?  Since you're using "deviceptr", this implies that you're using CUDA.

Also, if you can post a complete reproducing example, it would be easier to help determine the issue.

Comment: Yes Mat, is my intention that the outer loop to be sequential, because indeed there is a dependency loop. In principle the problem solution admits parallelization of the reduction part only. This seams OK for me because it works when solving the L factor.
About the data management, I'm creating gpu memory regions with acc_malloc + acc_memcpy_to_device to pass the L and U factors on the CSR format (ia, ja, factorVals). To recover the solution I simply do acc_memcpy_from_device to get the memory region with the result to the host and further compared with my cpu solution.

Comment: Yes, I missed that x was being read.  You performance will be poor since you'll be under utilizing the GPU, but that's not at issue here.  I'd need to see a reproducing example to better help on where the wrong answer is coming from.